# How to select multiple files using java.awt.FileDialog

Tags: java, awt

Is it possible to select multiple files using java.awt.FileDialog?

Because I want my dialog to have the OSX finder interface, I can't use JFileChooser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Javadoc it seems to be possible in [JDK7](http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html) (see `setMultipleMode(boolean)` or `getFiles()` which returns an array of files). However cross checking with the Javadoc for [JDK6](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html) it is not possible in older versions...

Comment: Too bad OSX doesn't support JDK7 -.-

Comment: @MrThys: Since Java7's not out yet, that's not surprising.

Comment: Still for Linux and Windows there are snapshot binaries http://download.java.net/jdk7/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the options (default is false)

setMultiSelectionEnabled(true)

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setMultiSelectionEnabled(boolean)

Comment: I quote myself; "Because I want my dialog to have the OSX finder interface, I can't use JFileChooser."

Comment: @MrThys sorry , was too quick to answer. brb