# Selecting few files as input in a Java program

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select multiple files using java.awt.FileDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182100/how-to-select-multiple-files-using-java-awt-filedialog)

I'm writing a small java program that takes a file as input, reads the data, and prints the desire output to a file. I created a small JPanel where you can select the input and output files. I used [FileDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html) 
to select the input file. The program works great, but I want to know if I can have the ability to select few files in the FileDialog and it will return an array of files. because sometimes the input will be split between few files.

Please give me any ideas you have.

Thanks

Comment: Use a [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) instead. It allows you to select multiple files and return them as an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);` on your `FileDialog`, but only if you are using JDK7.

For older JDK versions the alternative is to use `setMultiSelectionEnabled(boolean b)` on a `javax.swing.JFileChooser`

Comment: Thank you very much. that was an easy answer :)

Comment: I'm getting errors when doing **File[] selectedFiles = fd.getFiles();**

Comment: @Mike If your `fd` object is a `FileDialog`, it's because there is no such method: `getFiles()` in JDK5. Only starting with JDK7 that method exists.

Comment: @Mike See the `Since: 1.7` from [FileDialog from JDK7 JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html#getFiles())

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use AWT? If not then look at the swing JFileChooser. There is a [setMultiSelectionEnabled](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setMultiSelectionEnabled%28boolean%29) method that will help

If you need the FileDialog component then look at this [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html#setMultipleMode%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

Copied from [How to select multiple files using java.awt.FileDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182100/how-to-select-multiple-files-using-java-awt-filedialog)

> According to Javadoc it seems to be possible in [JDK7](http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html) (see
>   `setMultipleMode(boolean)` or `getFiles()` which returns an array of
>   files). However cross checking with the Javadoc for [JDK6](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html) it is
>   not possible in older versions...

Comment: You copied the answer and couldn't even format it the same?

Comment: Sorry I thought it was a good way to help the partner. I'm learning.

Comment: It is better to leave a comment on the question, with a link to the other question, than to copy it into an answer. We close duplicate questions, so that they point to a single one eventually anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) and call [getSelectedFiles()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFiles%28%29) ? Tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).